# Javascript method clearInterval does not cancel pending HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, performance

I am using IntersectionObserver API to check whether elements are in focus or not. If in focus, then I am creating a poll job for each element using setInterval which will trigger HTTP calls to get some get from the server. If those elements go out of focus then I am cancelling that particular poll using clearInterval.

The problem that I am seeing now is a few HTTP calls triggered by those poll jobs(cancelled ones) are in the pending state even after calling clearInterval. Because of this behaviour, HTTP calls triggered by elements which are now in focus are getting delayed. Is there any way to cancel all the pending HTTP calls which were triggered by old poll jobs?

I tried using the window.stop() but I am looking any other approaches.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController (but it's experimental).

Comment: @FelixKling Let me read about it.Thanks.

Comment: There's also a more cross-browser solution to [abort a request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) in the XHR object itself. Also, [timing out a request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout) is possible.